# Reading from unstructured data in excel in specified formats

Tags: excel, etl, data-conversion, structured-data

I'm trying to convert unstructured data found in XL into a predefined formats.  The situation is that the input data will have a number of different layouts.  Imagine the following situation:
You have a number of suppliers that sends a batch of invoices in XL format, each one of them have their own format and they are unlikely to standardise in a predefined layout. You want to "read" from these layouts and conver them in one common layout having for example: item code, description, quantity and retail price. These are common fields that ALL invoices would have BUT some may, for example, use the wording Barcode or Unique Code or Product Code instead of "Item Code".  Hence, the solution I'm looking for is to have a program to teach it that when they meet supplier name X found in row 2 cell 3 it should look for the column "Item Code" and when they meet supplier with name Y found in row 10 cell 6 they should look for column "Barcode" etc..etc..  The program would then extract the item codes, descriptions, quantities and retail prices found on each row into a new sheet/workbook in one common / standard template.

I'm a .NET developer and currently I'm doing this type of logic, hard coded, to read such unstructured data and converted it into a "standard" way.  I can't find any software on the market that can "teach it" to read from a source and convert it into another source. How would you tackle such challenge?

Comment: I would start by creating a structured format and enforcing its use throughout the system.

Comment: Problem is that we do not have control on the input data.